# Simple HTML/CSS - positioning div's

Tags: html, css

I've recently gotten into the world of HTML/CSS and I am struggling with something.

I want to position the div's like this:
[image: http://toresveaass.no/toresveaass/DivQuestion.png]

But the I only manage to it like this:
[image: http://toresveaass.no/toresveaass/DivQuestion-2.png]

As you see, I want div 5 to be below Div 4, and next to div 3. But I only

Of course, I can wrap div 4 and div 5 in a new div, but I'd rather learn a better way of doing this.

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#banner {
  background-color: green;
}
#topp-meny {
  background-color: pink;
}
#side-meny {
  background-color: violet;
  float: left;
}
#innhold {
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">Webutvikling</div>

<div id="topp-meny">Meny</div>


<div id="side-meny">
  <p>sidemeny</p>
</div>

<div id="innhold">
  <p>innhold</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping divs 4 and 5 in another div is not a *bad* or _wrong way_ to do it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gfnb09b8/ like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a better way to do so without wrapping in a `DIV` your Div 4 and 5. But in place of using `float`, you can specify a `width` to each div and display them as `display : inline-block;` (a bit better).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#banner {
  background-color: green;
}
#topp-meny {
  background-color: pink;
}
#side-meny {
  background-color: violet;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#innhold {
  background-color: grey;
}
#footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
#wrapping {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">Webutvikling</div>
<div id="topp-meny">Meny</div>
<div id="side-meny">
  <p>sidemeny</p>
</div>
<div id="wrapping">
  <div id="innhold">
    <p>innhold</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without wrapping, you can add a `height` (in PX, not in %) to your Div 3 so that Div 5 remain of the right. I don't really like this option...

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    #banner {
      background-color: green;
    }
    #topp-meny {
      background-color: pink;
    }
    #side-meny {
      background-color: violet;
      float: left;
      height: 50px;
    }
    #innhold {
      background-color: grey;
      float: left;
      width: 90%
    }
    #footer {
      background-color: blue;
      float: left;
      width: 90%
    }
```

```html
<div id="banner">Webutvikling</div>
<div id="topp-meny">Meny</div>
<div id="side-meny">
  <p>sidemeny</p>
</div>
<div id="innhold">
  <p>innhold</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that you need to specify a static height for your sub-menu...

Answer (score 0):

Going by the diagram you supplied:

```
#side-meny {
  float:left
}
```

Make a new div containing #innhold and #footer, let's call it #right-container so you have

```
<div id="right-container">
  <div id="innhold">
    <p>innhold</p>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>footer</p>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Then

```
#right-container {
  float:right
}
```

See if that works.

Comment: OP mentioned this solution in their question but wants to find *a better way* of achieving said layout. I fully support your answer (wrapping the two divs) and think you should provide support for this method as to why the OP should use it that speaks directly to the *a better way* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code which I have modified.

```
     body {
        background-color: yellow;
        }
     #banner {
        background-color: green;
        }
     #topp-meny {
        background-color: pink;
        }
     #side-meny {
        background-color: violet;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 25%;
        }
     #block {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 74%;
        }
     #block p {
        margin: 0;
        }
        #innhold {
        background-color: grey;
      }
     #footer {
        background-color: blue;
        clear: both;
        }
      
     <div id="banner">Webutvikling</div>
     <div id="topp-meny">Meny</div>
     <div id="side-meny">
      <p>sidemeny</p>
      </div>
      <div id="block">
      <div id="innhold">
      <p>innhold</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your css file you can set

```
#footer{
    ...
    position:absolute;
    left: (div3's width);
    top: (div1+div2+div4 height)
 }
```